# Detecting button press using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to detect whether a button is pressed using AJAX and PHP (ofcourse this is part of a test not my actual aim). I can detect whenever I type something in a textbox but cannot detect whether a button is pressed or not.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert(){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById('adiv').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open('GET','AJAX.inc.php?search='+document.getElementById('search_text').value+'search_button=Search!', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="search_text" name="search" onkeyup="load();">
<input type="submit" name="search_button" value="Search!">
<div id="adiv"></div>
</body>
</html>

And here's my AJAX file:

<?php
if(isset($_GET['search_button'])){
echo 'You pressed a button!';
}
?>
```

Comment: I would tick this if it were an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button is not in a `form`, you can simply use `<button>` or `<input type="button">`.

You can use `<button onclick="insert();">Search!</button>` to listener to button press event.

Comment: Infact I deleted it due to some reason and forgot to add it back, this is the second time today someone pointed my silly mistake out. Anyway well spot, you deserve the tick.